# Vue programatically force refresh data even with v-once

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, nuxt.js

The idea is as follows:

I have a component with this template:

```
<span class="message" v-once>
    {{ headline }}
</span>
```

I have the `v-once` directive on the headline text since when the component is actually being used on a live environment, there is no way for the headline text to change.

Now, I'm building a tool in which we are able to look at details of all our components. With this tool, I have a Message input on the page which allows user to modify the text that is seen in the component. This is working fine as long as `v-once` doesn't exist.

For optimization purposes, I would like to have the `v-once` directive in place, but I just need a way to override this once in my tool. I was hoping I could make use of `$forceUpdate()`, but it doesn't do the trick (probably still taking `v-once` into consideration).

Is there a way to accomplish this? If not, I can just leave the `v-once` off of it, but would be nice.

Comment: The point of `v-once` is that you can't change it. If you need to change it I think you should just leave it off. I can't imagine `v-once` provides a meaningful improvement to performance or anything.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question. I don't think you should try to refresh a component with a `v-once` directive, since as you mentioned the purpose of use it is to render once and treat that component as a static content, that way your component gets better performance.

From docs:

> Rendering plain HTML elements is very fast in Vue, but sometimes you might have a component that contains a lot of static content. In these cases, you can ensure that it’s only evaluated once and then cached by adding the v-once directive to the root element, like this:

```
<div v-once>
    <h1>Terms of Service</h1>
    ... a lot of static content ...
</div>
```

Therefore, you could use a computed property to get better performance, since are cached based on their dependencies, from docs:

> A computed property will only re-evaluate when some of its dependencies have changed. This means as long as message has not changed, multiple access to the reversedMessage computed property will immediately return the previously computed result without having to run the function again.

Final thoughts: If your component will or could update the data element (and you want your app display those changes), you should not be using `v-once` directive.